# Invalid outside procedure

Tags: ms-access, vba

This is driving me up a wall. I have this very simple code to fill in another field on the update of Customer field.

```
Private Sub Customer_AfterUpdate()

Me.File_path = Me.Last_Name & " " & Me.First_Name

End Sub
```

And it returns `invalid outside procedure` for the line `private sub customer afterupdate()`

What ever could I be doing wrong?

Comment: do you have any accidental/ extra  `end sub` lines in your vba editor?

Comment: You are right. I had a Sub with no code in it. Once I deleted that it all worked. Infinite thanks.

Comment: I will add as an answer if that's ok

Comment: Ok I wasn't sure how to do that. thanks.

Comment: I see you are new to SO, [this link may help you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Glad you got your code working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is a compile error rather than a runtime error.

It usually occurs when there is unrecognised text out side of a procedure. Likely causes are stray/accidental/extra `sub` or `end sub` lines.

This can also be caused where public variables are given an incorrect or unacceptable data type. This is just another example of text that is unrecognised and outside the bounds of a procedure.